# Getline error undefined

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>   
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

  int countLines( ifstream& in  )
    {
        int count = 0;
        char line[80];
        if ( in.good() )
        {
            //while ( !feof( in ) )
                while( getline( in,line ) ) count++;
            in.seekg(ios::beg);
        }
        return count;
    }
```

No matching function for call get line
What does it mean?
I have included all of the headers but why I still can not call get line?

Comment: Look up a `std::getline` reference and look for example code and parameters. Compare the parameter types to your argument types and use the example to help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a std::string instead of a character array for calling string's `getline()` function. Replace your `char line[80]` with a `std::string line` and it will work.

Check the documentation here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

Comment: @salgar I have tried to #include <iostream> too but cannot. In fact, when I include it and use cout instead of printf it will create another error that said cout is not defined. Is there something wrong with my header ? but I have tried in microsoft visual studio too.